# PostgreSQL Binary Replication -do i really need to copy pg_xlog separated?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am doing postgresql replication by issuing:

On the **master**:

```
>select pg_start_backup('clone', true);
>\q 
#tar -cz main -f main.tar.gz
```

(Explanation: main is the data directory on my system /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main)

Then I transfer main.tar.gz to the **slave**....

On the **slave**:

```
--Uncompressing main.tar.gz.... 
#tar -zxf main.tar.gz 
--Copying previously created recovery.conf 
#cp recovery.conf main/
--And then just starts the slave
#service postgresql start
```

On the **master**:

```
--And stoping backup mode on the master:
>select pg_stop_backup();
```

What I get is that replication **is working fine**, and it really works nice.

But I am with doubt after reading the official documentation that after the copy I should copy pg_xlog  in an additional step... https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial

But I never do that, and never experienced a problem - do a lot of tests, like counting every table lines, in both master and slave and much more, but what worst can happen?

Comment: You can use `pg_basebackup` to do all that in a single step

Comment: And what about the additional step ? should i do two pg_basebackup or only one?

Comment: pg_basebackup can copy the needed WAL archives while it takes the backup To do that specify `-X fetch` or `-X stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, until it doesn't.  Then you get a backup which won't start, will start but won't connect the master to stream new data, or perhaps one which will start but is silently corrupted (unlikely, but I wouldn't rule it out). Have you tested this method for a very large server under very heavy load?

If you use `pg_basebackup`, it will either take care of it for you, or will notify you that the backup failed before you discover that the hard way, or notify you that you need to have a separate WAL archive.  Depending on which version of PostgreSQL and which options you give to `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: But pg_basebackup will do exactly the same i am doing isn't?

Comment: It depends on what version you use and what options you give it.  On v10, the default will use a temporary replication slot to guarantee the WAL to be retained long enough.  If you change to -X stream, it uses a 2nd connection to collect WAL as it is generated, so it is more likely to succeed than your method but is still not guaranteed under extremely heavy load.  -X fetch is more or less the same as your method, except failures are detected at the time the backed is taken, rather than the time it is put into use.